# Insert Method do not insert data neither throws an exception - Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

One of the methods of my app should set the data into its database.
The problem I'm facing is that the insert method (Provided by SQLite Android Class) does not insert any data at the end and it didn't throws an exception either.

Here is the method's code:

```
public void setGasto(int idRubrica, String estabelecimento, float valor){
    SQLiteDatabase db2 = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);

    values.put("DATA", System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put("VALOR",valor);
    values.put("ESTABELECIMENTO", estabelecimento);
    values.put("ID_RUBRICA",idRubrica);


    db2.beginTransaction();
    try{
        db2.insertOrThrow("GASTOS",null,values);
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    db2.endTransaction();
    db2.close();

}
```

I got stuck with it.

Update.

I think that the problem resides in the way I'm calling it.
I call it from a Inner Method that is set to an Alert Dialog Builder.

```
public  void dismiss(AlertDialog.Builder builder, final SQLiteDatabase db2){
    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            db.setGasto(db2, idRubrica,estabelecimento,valor);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You code seems to be ok. How do you check if there is any entry in your DB?

Comment: Hello @AdrienCadet, I'm acessing it from SQL Browser.

Comment: But actually I suspect that the problem is somehow because I'm calling it within an inner method of my Alert Dialog window, 

I edited the post to show the inner method which calls the insert

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setTransactionSuccessful()` before `endTransaction()` to commit the changes. Otherwise `endTransaction()` rolls back the changes.

The canonical pattern for transactions is as follows:

```
beginTransaction();
try {
    db operations...
    setTransactionSuccessful();
}
finally {
    endTransaction();
}
```

This ensures the begin and end calls are always paired.